# Faking checkbox behaviour with Bootstrap buttons-checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, jquery-events

I'm trying to use the data-toggle attribute of Bootstrap to allow the user to select the privilege level.

I have put together a [simple demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28xsr/), the expected values are:

- None: 0
- User: 1
- Administrator: 2
- User + Administrator = 3

The problem is that the computed value seems to be one step behind of the actual toggled buttons.

I'm pretty sure this is a pretty simple problem, but so far the solution has managed to elude me.

---

Apparently, I'm required to duplicate the JSFiddle code here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#privileges button').click(function () {
        var privileges = 0;

        //$(this).addClass('active');

        $('#privileges button').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                privileges += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
            }
        });

        $('input[id="user[privileges]"]').val(privileges);
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<label for="user[privileges]">Privileges</label>
<input id="user[privileges]" name="user[privileges]" type="text" value="0">
<div id="privileges" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" style="width: 100%;">
    <button type="button" class="btn" style="width: 50%;" value="1">User</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" style="width: 50%;" value="2">Administrator</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#privileges button').click(function () {
        var privileges = 0;
        var alredySelected = $(this).hasClass('active');

        //$(this).addClass('active');

        $('#privileges button').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                privileges += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
            }
        });
        if(alredySelected){
            privileges = parseInt(privileges) - parseInt($(this).val());
        } else {
            privileges = parseInt(privileges) + parseInt($(this).val());
        }

        $('input[id="user[privileges]"]').val( privileges);
    });


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28xsr/1/